# how to Mapping Camel Unmarshal CSV to Dozer Bean

Tags: java, spring, csv, apache-camel, dozer

Using Camel I am splitting file

```
<unmarshal>
    <csv delimiter="|"/>
</unmarshal>
<split>
    <simple>${body}</simple> <!-- Body will be a list of lists -->
    <choice>
        <when>
            <simple>${body[0]} == '100'</simple>
            <to uri="bean:processor100"/>
        </when>         
        <when>
            <simple>${body[0]} == '200'</simple>
            <to uri="bean:processor200"/>
        </when>
    </choice>
```

In each Bean I am writing

```
public void process(List<String> csvRows) {
object.setcol1(csvRows.get(1));
object.setcol2(csvRows.get(2));
object.setcol3(csvRows.get(3));
```

I am thinking a way using `jxls` to externalize the mapping in some mapping file.

Is there any way where I can pull mappings from external source (properties file or XML) & bind directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering own question

Solved using BeanIO.

BeanIO mapping XML file which get mappings.

Comment: Could you please accept this answer so that it's no longer listed as unanswered? Thanks!